# What should I write in the "organisation" field when applying for a Bangladeshi MRV?

Tags: visas, bangladesh

I'm applying for [a machine-readable visa to Bangladesh](https://www.visa.gov.bd/) and I'm stuck on the last question of part 1, where it says "organisation". Does anyone know what this means? What does it wants me to put in the "other" boxes? It’s not letting me move to the next stage without filling it out.

Comment: MRV: machine readable visa https://www.visa.gov.bd/ and yes I’m applying to go visit Bangladesh for pleasure and require a visa

Comment: Sounds like where you work?